# how to get the maximum value of a varchar column and auto increment it

Tags: mysql, sql, database

i want to get the maximum value of my varchar column which must be unique thats why i want to get the max value and increment it.

For example i have this situation from tbl_check:

```
+---------------+
|  check_up_id  |
-----------------
|      1-0      |
|      1-2      |
|      11-1     |
|      111-3    |
|      12-4     |
|      52-5     |
|      1-6      |
|      1-7      |
|      3-9      |
|      3-8      |
|      3-11     |
|      3-10     |
+---------------+
```

in my check_up_id considered that i have incremented the right side ( 1 - **) of my id which is not in order. Now what i wan't is how can i query to get the maximum value of the right side. Only right side to be considered, in that situation that i have sometimes 3 digits or 2 digits or sometimes only one digit in the left side. What i want is to return the largest value of the right side. In my example i want to return the 3-11 in my query. Disregard the incremental because i will do it in php side. What i want is to return the largest value of the right side after the ( - )

Comment: @Barmar hello sir.. thanks for your reply. i tried this but error? SELECT
MAX(CAST (SUBSTRING_INDEX(check_up_id,'-',-1))) AS DECIMAL
FROM
tbl_check_up

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
SELECT MAX(CAST(SUBSTRING_INDEX(check_up_id, '-', -1) AS DECIMAL))
FROM tbl_check
```

`SUBSTRING_INDEX` returns the substring of a column containing the specified number of fields delimited by the `-` character. The negative count means to count from the right, so this returns the rightmost field.

To get the whole field that contains this, use it in a `JOIN`:

```
SELECT check_up_id
FROM tbl_check
JOIN (
    SELECT MAX(CAST(SUBSTRING_INDEX(check_up_id, '-', -1) AS DECIMAL)) as max_right
    FROM tbl_check) AS x
ON SUBSTRING_INDEX(check_up_id, '-', -1) = max_right
```

Comment: hello sir thanks for your answer. [Err] 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ') AS DECIMAL))
FROM tbl_check_up' at line 1

Comment: Sorry, had an extra `)`

Comment: thanks sir. sir can i have the whole value return. because it returns only 11. i want the  3-11 exactly

Comment: The question says you want the maximum value of the right side.

Comment: yes sir. i want the maximum value of the right side but i want to return the whole data that has the maximum value of the right side. sorry sir. . please help me thanks

Comment: I've added that to the answer

Comment: It would really be better if you split the field into two columns. Then you could use `AUTO_INCREMENT` on that part, or at least add an index to it.

Comment: so i need the first answer you put sir? and manipulate in php the left side? is that what you mean sir?. also  i want ur suggestion because i am just a beginner

Comment: Use the second query to get what you want.

Comment: hello sir @Barmar. can you help me again with this? You have an error in your SQL syntax;. when i put it in my model why it says like this? but when i run the query in mysql it works good. Here is my function model : public function checkupID() {
     $query = $this->db->query(' SELECT check_up_id FROM tbl_check_up JOIN (SELECT MAX(CAST(SUBSTRING_INDEX(check_up_id, '-', -1) AS DECIMAL)) as max_right FROM tbl_check_up) AS x
                    ON SUBSTRING_INDEX(check_up_id, '-', -1) = max_right ');
     return $query->result();
    }

Comment: Make sure you're using different quotes to delimit the PHP string than you're using for the strings inside the query.